# rake import- only adding one line from csv to database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am attempting to import a CSV file into my rails database (SQLite in Development) following this [tutorial](http://dwradcliffe.com/2011/12/29/import-csv.html). Data is actually getting inserted into my database but it seems to only insert the first record from the CSV File. the rake seems to run without problem. and a running it with --trace reveals no additional information.

```
require 'csv'
desc "Import Voters from CSV File"
task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "db/GOTV.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers  => false) do |row|
    Voter.create({
      :last_name              => row[0], 
      :first_name             => row[1],
      :middle_name            => row[2],
      :name_suffix            => row[3],
      :primary_address        => row[4],
      :primary_city           => row[5],
      :primary_state          => row[6],
      :primary_zip            => row[7],
      :primary_zip4           => row[8],
      :primary_unit           => row[9],
      :primary_unit_number    => row[10],
      :phone_number           => row[11],
      :phone_code             => row[12],
      :gender                 => row[13],
      :party_code             => row[14],
      :voter_score            => row[15],
      :congressional_district => row[16],
      :house_district         => row[17],
      :senate_district        => row[18],
      :county_name            => row[19],
      :voter_key              => row[20],
      :household_id           => row[21],
      :client_id              => row[22],
      :state_voter_id         => row[23]
      })
  end
end
```

Comment: You checked that the foreach is correctly iterating through all the rows of the file ? I mean problem could either be that it stops iterating after the first line, or it goes through all the lines but only saves the first somehow, so you could check that first

Comment: i've tried to put row[0] to log it out to the console but it throws and undefined method error.

Comment: it's either `p` or `puts` not `put`

Comment: yep the foreach is only hitting the first record and then stops

Comment: so this might be because of the end of line (EOL) character

Comment: i've tried all the different row_sep types listed in the ruby csv docs. all have the same result. the file was a windows csv file. and the eol appears to be a return

Comment: Does it work if you add this: {:row_sep => "\r\n"}

Comment: tried that one as well same result.

Comment: You should open up the file in a binary editor and confirm what the EOL separator is, because sounds like Windows has put something weird there.

Comment: There are some gems that help you solve your specific problems here at [Knight.io's Spreadsheet (Ruby) section](http://www.knight.io/categories/spreadsheets-ruby).

Comment: Have you solved this yet? I think I just ran into the same issue. With Ruby1.8 it only processes one line, with Ruby 1.9 it works fine.. However if the second arg('options') to foreach is nil (or missing) - it will work in 1.8 as well.. really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this as well - guess you solved it some other way, but still might be useful for others.

In my case, the issue seems to be an incompatible change in the CSV library.

I guess you were using Ruby 1.8, where

```
CSV.foreach(path, rs = nil, &block)
```

The docs here are severely lacking, actually no docs at all, so have to guess from source: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach..
Anyway, 'rs' is clearly not an option hash, it looks like the record separator.

In Ruby 1.9 this is nicer: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach

```
self.foreach(path, options = Hash.new, &block)
```

so this is the one that supports options such as `:headers`..